# Terminal Command to display a single line from a text file in OS X

Tags: terminal, command-line

I want to display at a specific line, e.g. line 4, from a text file in Terminal (I need this for character counts, using `wc`). I'm sure this is a simple problem but `read -e 1 filename` doesn't do it.

What can be used to accomplish this task?

Comment: Thanks. I expect that some form of cat or pr would also do it. I used:head -n 2 filename | tail -n 1 | wc -m That gives the number of characters + 1 (an end of line char?) <br/>

Answer (score 8):

You can use `sed` command:

```
sed -n '4p' YOUR_FILE
```

Or `head`/`tail` combination:

```
head -n 4 YOUR_FILE | tail -n 1
```